# Java Apache Commons Math, linear least squares (fitting) with constraints

Tags: java, apache-commons, curve-fitting, linear-regression, least-squares

I'm trying to use Apache Commons Math library in Java (latest version) to solve a linear least squares problem, where there is a constraint on the solution.

Specifically, I want the solution to contain positive only values.  In other words, I want to find the best fit of my basis functions such that the solution weights are greater than 0.

If anyone has already tracked this particular problem down and solved it, I would be grateful for the solution!